# How can I use a WeMo controller on a non-standard outlet?

Tags: hvac, receptacle, cord-and-plug

I have an older A/C unit that uses a [6-15p plug](http://internationalconfig.com/documents/30255.pdf). I want to be able to remotely control the unit with a WeMo, but it uses a 5-15r receptacle and plug. The A/C unit says its rated for 208V, and I believe the WeMo is able to support this much as well. How can I best convert the plugs to accommodate the WeMo? I'm thinking of something like **[this](http://internationalconfig.com/icc6.asp?item=30255)** that the WeMo will plug into, that can then be plugged into the wall. What can I put between the 6-15p and the WeMo though?

Comment: can your AC unit be connected to a separate thermostat maybe you could try a wifi thermostat?

Answer (score 2):

Adapting a 120V controller for a 240V (208 is unlikely unless you have 3-phase power) plug seems remarkably foolish...

Quoting wikipedia: "NEMA 6 devices, while specified as 250 V, may be used for either 208 V or 240 V circuits, generally depending on whether the building has a three-phase or split-phase power supply, respectively."

To Quote Belkin, Wemo ratings: "Max 120V~/16A/60Hz/1800W"

Either educate yourself far enough to use a 240V relay with a 120V coil to control the A/C (plug the COIL into the WeMo) or forget this as baaaaaaad idea.

Comment: Hahah, I suppose the worst that could happen is that the device just wouldn't power on, or I'd blow the WeMo?

Comment: The WeMo is rated for 120V. Putting 208V or 240V is likely to destroy it, possibly violently.

Comment: I'm guessing this wouldn't work either:http://www.homedepot.com/p/Macally-Portable-Universal-Power-Plug-Adaptor-LP-PTC/205594953#specifications

Comment: I have given you a method that will work. Please stop trying to kill yourself (yes Virginia, electrocution is an option) or start a fire with inappropriate adapters.

Comment: Any ideas on where I can find a wireless control unit similar to WeMo(that works over wifi, not a provided remote) that can take in 208v?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Something like this: https://www.1000bulbs.com/product/89373/SUN-734145.html, but that can run over wifi.

Answer (score 0):

If the j-box has a neutral (it may or may not), you could wire up the WeMo to switch only one of the hot legs. I won't describe the details of my proposal since it involves rewiring the outlet and daisy-chaining some additional outlets and plugs, but it could be done. If this is enough info to jog your creativity, go for it. If you don't know what I'm talking about, please don't.

(As others have said, if you plug the WeMo into both hot legs, e.g. with one of those international adapters, you are likely to fry the device and/or start a fire.)